# SpriteKit game pan map when approaching edge

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am creating a 2D side-view sprite kit game, and I would like to start panning across the map when the "player" gets within 100 pixels of the edge of the screen. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends how your map is set up. You can check if your "player" , which I'm presuming is a SKSpriteNode, is at your 100 pixel threshold by:

```
-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {

[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"playerNode" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {

    if (node.position.x > self.frame.size.width-100){
       // move your map
    }

    }];

}
```

How you actually move your map depends on how you set it up. If it is one big SKSpriteNode itself you can move that, maybe with an SKAction:

```
SKAction *moveMap = [SKAction moveByX: yourMapMovingDistance y:0 duration:yourDuration];
[mapNode runAction: moveMap];
```